# Continuity of the reciprocal of a map of metric spaces in a neighborhood

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

The question is the following:
Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function (where $\mathbb{R}$ is a metric space
using the standard distance $d(a, b) = |a − b|$ for all a, b $∈$ $\mathbb{R}$). Show that if a $∈$ X is such that $f(a)$ is not equal to zero,
then there is an $r > 0$ such that the function $1/f$ is defined and is continuous on $B(a, r)$.

I am able to find a neighbourhood for which f is non-zero (by choosing epsilon to be $|f(a)/2|$ and then using continuity to find an $r>0$, yet I am unsure of how to show that $1/f$ is continuous at all points in this neighbourhood. I would very much appreciate any hints, thanks.

Comment: Hint: post-compose $f$ with the (continuous) map $x \mapsto 1/x$. This is possible on $B(a,r)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\left\vert \frac{1}{f(x)} - \frac{1}{f(a)} \right\vert= \frac{\vert f(x) -f(a) \vert}{\vert f(x) \vert \vert f(a) \vert} \le 2\frac{\vert f(x) -f(a) \vert}{\vert f(a) \vert^2}$$

On a ball $B(a,r)$ on which $\vert f(x) \vert \ge \frac{\vert f(a) \vert}{2} > 0$.